# Assignement of a variable inside a concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, concatenation

I have a global variable `var num_tab=1;`, a function that creates a link a href :

```
function Addsomething()
{
$("#tout").html("<a style=\""+"margin-left:-20px;"+"\" onClick=\"eval(num_tab=2)\"  href=\""+"#tab1"+"\" data-toggle=\""+"tab"+"\">SELECT</a>");
Bla,Bla..

$("#champ1").append('<li id=\"1\" class="champ" onclick="insertAtCaret(&quot;sousTab'+num_tab+'&quot;);" value=\"1\">1</li>');

}
```

What i want to do is to create a href that when clicked changes the value of the variable num_tab, but if you can see the href is inside a jquery html(), which makes me confused about how to assign a value to the variable. I almost tried everything: `onClick=\"num_tab=2\"`,`onClick=\""+num_tab+"=2\"`

Actually i tried something: when i write onclick='num_tab=2;alert("+num_tab+");' i still get the initial value of num_tab, seems it's more like a problem of local and global variable and i can't figure out it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use `eval()`. It's insecure and not the appropriate tool for this job. Just assign a function to the onclick:

```
$("#tout").html("<a onclick='set_num_tab(2)'">);   //fill out the rest of this line

function set_num_tab(value) {
    num_tab = value;
}
```

That should give you an idea of how to do it. btw there's no reason you can't use single quotes around an onclick like that.

Alternately, this would work:

```
$("#tout").html("<a onclick='num_tab=2'">);
```

But that's pretty messy. I try to avoid inline JavaScript.

Comment: well, you're still using `eval()`, which is not necessary. try changing your `onclick` in your first example to `onClick='num_tab=2;alert(num_tab);return false;'`. There's no reason that wouldn't work if `num_tab` is declared globally.

Comment: But it didn't work, seems like when i write `onClick='num_tab=2'` it's a different variable than the global one. Even if i declare the varibale inside the function it doesn't work. In concatenation we are able to extract the value of a variable but it's not possible to assign a value to a variable (or at least i didn't figure out the way to do it).

Comment: By the way i tried `onClick='window.num_tab=2'` and it didn't work as well :(

Comment: Unless you post the part of your code where you declare `num_tab` I can't help you. In my test `onClick='num_tab=2;alert(num_tab);return false;'` worked fine when `num_tab` was a global variable.